# Invoke parent prototype method

Tags: javascript

"I have the problem with understanding. piece of my code:

```
       //constructor
       function Widget (options) {            
        };

       //return the string
        Widget.prototype._addEditFormString = function (val) {
            return "<input type='text' value='" + val + "' >";                
        } 
        //initializing method
        Widget.prototype.init = function () {
            var addRowButton = document.getElementsByName("addRow")[0];              
            addRowButton.addEventListener("click", this.addRow, false);                
        };
        //this context in this method still confusing me
        Widget.prototype.addRow = function () {    
            console.log(this._addEditFormString);//Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method '_addEditFormString'                  
        }  
        var wid = new Widget();

         wid.init();
```

The problem - In init() method I add event listener (addRow method), but in addRow method I dont know how to catch "this" of my contructor class, because I want to invoke _addEditFormString() method, but receive "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Window] has no method '_addEditFormString'". How I can fix that without Widget.prototype._addEditFormString? Or that only one solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the context in the event handler is the window, not your `Widget`.

Change

```
Widget.prototype.init = function () {
     var addRowButton = document.getElementsByName("addRow")[0];              
     addRowButton.addEventListener("click", this.addRow, false);                
};
```

to

```
Widget.prototype.init = function () {
      var _this = this;
      var addRowButton = document.getElementsByName("addRow")[0];              
      addRowButton.addEventListener("click", function(){_this.addRow()}, false);                
};
```

---

Edit regarding your question in comment :

you seem to want

```
Widget.prototype._addEditFormString.call(this);
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but problem to catch "this" in addRow() cause addEventListener pass in "this" as BUTTON. how to invoke Widget.prototype._addEditFormString() like this._addEditFormString()?

Comment: @user1506183 I'm not sure I get your question but I edited my answer with what I get.

Comment: yes. get this, many thanks function(){_this.addRow()} resolve my problem )